# Loop through a table and add entries based on conditions

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
Table A (id, rollNumber, spaces)
```

example data

```
1 1 A
2 1 B
3 1 C
4 2 A
5 3 A
```

For every rollnumber there should be 3 spaces namely A , B , C . 
However currently the entries are not consistent. Some have it and some dont .

I have to iterate through the table and add B , C spaces for any rollNumber that doesnt have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to generate a calendar table containing all the distinct data you would expect to appear.  Then, use `MINUS` with an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to populate the missing data.

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (rollNumber, spaces)
SELECT r.rollNumber, s.spaces
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT rollNumber FROM yourTable
) r
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 'A' AS spaces UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C'
) s
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON r.rollNumber = t.rollNumber AND s.spaces = t.spaces
WHERE
    t.rollNumber IS NULL;
```

Comment: mysql doesnt seem to recognise the minus keyword .

Comment: @AnindaChoudhary Sorry, I updated my answer to use a join instead.  Hopefully it works now.

Comment: works perfect. been stuck on this a long time with my limited knowledge of databases . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT rollNumber FROM t) r
  CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT spaces FROM t) s
  LEFT JOIN t
    ON s.spaces = t.spaces
    AND r.rollNumber = t.rollNumber
```

The subtables `r` and `s` extract every possible value for `rollNumber` and `spaces`; the CROSS JOIN makes every possible combination of those values. A LEFT JOIN with the original table will then give you all of those combinations, filled with original data where possible.

Comment: I am looking to make these entries into the table and not just query them